# How can I concatenate these two values as a string?

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, c

I've tried all the supposed solutions for the exact error, pasted into google, that I could find on every forum including this one and no matter the alleged solution I will either get the error about unsigned int to char*, the error below, or invalid pointers.

Why is this platform so completely unfriendly in data type conversion? It's almost as if the creator/s never wanted any data types to be able convert.

Here's my code that is apparently useless:

```
  char* DeviceName = "Device-" +  ESP.getChipId();
  wifiManager.autoConnect(DeviceName);
```

Error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
   char* DeviceName = "Device-" +  ESP.getChipId();

Then I tried to use the pointers, but I have no idea what I'm doing and I keep getting invalid pointer errors, and/or invalid conversion errors.

Comment: Hint: Try using sprintf(). http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: char buffer [50];
  char DeviceName = sprintf(buffer, "Device-%d", ESP.getChipId());
  wifiManager.autoConnect(DeviceName);

Comment: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
   wifiManager.autoConnect(DeviceName);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the c function sprintf(, , ...)
The char array has to be big enough to hold your text plus a null to terminate the string.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  char out[20];
  sprintf(out, "Device-%08X",ESP.getChipId()); // %08X\n formats the hex and pads with 0s.

  Serial.println(out);
}

void loop() {}
```

Output:

```
Device-005D4D9D
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and it does output a numeric ID, but I wanted the string ID.

ESP8266 Chip ID = 005D4D9D <- this should be the ID...

Device-6114717 <- not the numeric conversion here

Comment: you are welcome - helpful user changed the format string to output 8 hex digits instead since that is what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Learning is good. To eliminate extra characters you can also use sprintf(out, "Device-%X",ESP.getChipId());